# How long does it take for a new question to appear on the homepage?

Tags: bug

I happened to hit the page twice within a couple of minutes and noticed by the timestamp, that it took about 30 minutes for a question to load (it was there the second time).

I knew they don't appear right away, but this got me wondering exactly how long does it take for a question to make it to the front page?

Comment: Actually I never noticed that. After I post a new question I think it always load immediately.

Answer (score 1):

There is a certain amount of caching going on, but questions would normally appear straight away -- caching in your web browser, or en-route, may hide this.

There is an in depth discussion [on how caching is used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69172/130044) over on [StackOverflow's Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)]